# Erlang: Get first n characters of a string

Tags: erlang

I have credit card number, let's say 5940043543536. And for security purposes I only want to display the first four digits.

How would one do that in erlang?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string in Erlang is just a list of integers, so you can use `lists:sublist/3`:

```
1> String = "5940043543536".
"5940043543536"
2> lists:sublist(String, 1, 4).
"5940"
```

Note that the position argument starts from `1` and not `0`.

Comment: Thanks! My familiarity with this terminology is still weak. I appreciate your fast response.

Answer (score 4):

In case you are receiving binary (instead of string)

```
binary:part(<<"123455678901234">>, 1, 4).   
<<"2345">>
```

or if you need get last four digits

```
binary:part(<<"123455678901234">>, {byte_size(<<"123455678901234">>), -4}).
<<"1234">>
```

Answer (score 3):

newer versions of Erlang have built in string functions. For your case

```
1> string:slice("123455678901234", 1, 4). 
"1234"
```

there is a string:substring function too, which works the same way, but it has been depreciated for slice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use pattern matching:

```erlang
1> String = "5940043543536".
"5940043543536"
2> [A,B,C,D|_] = String.         
"5940043543536"
3> [A,B,C,D].               
"5940"
```

Or you can create your own function, eg:

```erlang
1> String = "5940043543536".
"5940043543536"
2> GetDigits = fun F(_, Acc, 0) -> lists:reverse(Acc); 
                   F([H|T], Acc, N) -> F(T, [H|Acc], N - 1) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.43.91303403>
3> GetDigits(String, [], 4).
"5940"
```